# base c'tor with derived argument

Tags: c++

I created some class:

```
class Base{
public:
 Base(int = 0);
 ~Base();
 Base(Base&);
 Base(Derived&); //<- here
 int valueOfBase();
protected:
 int protectedData;
private:
 int baseData;
};

class Derived: public Base{
public:
    Derived(int = 0);
    Derived(Derived&);
    ~Derived();
private:
    int derivedData;
};

###//Impplementation in .cpp

Base::Base(Base& base)
{
    baseData = base.baseData;
    protectedData = base.protectedData;
    cout << "base Copy C'tor" << endl;
}

Base::Base(Derived& hello)
{
    baseData = hello.protectedData;
}
```

but when I try to compile some code I receive an erro (near `here`)

```
expected ) before & token
```

can I create base c'tor with derived argument for writing somethin like that

```
Derived derived(1);
Base base1 = derived;
```

if no why? 
thanks in  advance

Comment: I don't see the definitions of the constructors/destructor. Plus where is the definition of `Derived`?

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: is it ok, or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to provide the forward declaration of class `Derived`. See JoshD's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a forward declaration of `Derived`.

Try adding `class Derived;` above your Base class definition.